# Split last 1MB off a 1GB log file

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to extract the last 1MB of a 1GB log file on a mac.
When I use

```
split -b 1m
```

it creates a lot of files.
Is there a better way doing it?

Comment: Use tail command. Check the man page whether there is an option for bytes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the command, if you haven't found it yet.

```
tail -c 1048576 file.log > last1mb.log
```